# Easy Way To Switch Between Apps Similar To Alt+Tab or Command+Tab on iOS 6 Using Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: bluetooth, ipad, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch Between Apps With Alt-Tab / Command-Tab on iPad using Bluetooth Keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31356/switch-between-apps-with-alt-tab-command-tab-on-ipad-using-bluetooth-keyboard)

Previously I [asked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31356/switch-between-apps-with-alt-tab-command-tab-on-ipad-using-bluetooth-keyboard) if it was possible to do something similar to alt+tab or command+tab using the Apple Bluetooth Keyboard to quickly switch between apps like one might do on a desktop computer. That question related to iOS 5. The short answer was no.

Now that iOS 6 is out, is there anything in iOS 6 that would make this possible?

Comment: You could/should update your original question. You can start a bounty to draw some additional attention to it.

Comment: I could but I don't know if I should. I'm not sure if questions should be in a state of constant flux dependent on advances in technology. This isn't a big question but some more complex ones could be really impacted with such a policy. Let's say there is a good answer that is voted up 100 times and all of a sudden its wrong, are people to vote it down to negative 100? How will anyone know what's reliable? There are smarter people than me who can debate this but it seemed more appropriate to ask again for the new version of iOS.

Comment: Yes, ideally questions and answers are maintained and kept up to date. All StackExchange sites focus heavily on collaborative editing, which makes them much more like Wikipedia instead of a support forum.

Comment: @TomD Gerry is right: please edit your old question.